# Javascript/Mobile - onClick() wont work on mobile devices

Tags: javascript, http, mobile, reactjs

We have a website that when you click on the text it reads to you what is displayed. This works 100% for computers but on mobile devices it will not play the audio.

I have looked around the web but everything is pointing to Jquery using `touchstart`. We tried doing this but it then breaks on computers.

Anyone run into issues like this? If so, how did you fix it?

Comment: How does it break on computers?

Answer (score 0):

I think this was an issue with older versions of react. I haven't had the problem recently. In the past, I solved it by adding `cursor: pointer;` to the CSS of the element. It had something to do with events not firing on elements that aren't usually 'clickable'.